# tomcat not finding dependency jars when running from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I try to run a java web application with tomcat 7 in my eclipse (kepler) environment.
The application is compiled with maven for the dependencies.
The compilation works fine.
The application works fine on tomcat outside eclipse.
It used to work fine before we change maven targets.

Now when I try to run tomcat server in eclipse I have several `ClassNotFoundException` like :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I checked the war and it contains the jar jsf-api-1.2.jar as expected.
When I force this jar directly in my tomcar lib directory the application goes one step further but still fails on the same kind of exception.

I tried to clean everything I could, in eclipse without success.
I tried to change the deployement dependencies without success.

So far I just workaround the problem by doing remote debug from eclipse on my standalone tomcat.

Comment: so you have a working war file which works in tomcat but it does not work if you are using it from within Eclipse BUT you have changed the targets ? What kind of targets did you change and most important why did you change?

Comment: We had to change the repository location due to a server retirement. I did not do the change and the developper that did it does not have the problem in his environment. As far as I can see in the svn log, he also precised the versions for several dependencies.

Comment: He changed the version of Jersey we are using.